# Boost.Asio HTTP library

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

I'm searching for a high level advanced http library to write a native frontend for a large web application. Libraries based on `boost.asio` are preferred as I already use `boost` (and `asio`).

Cookie, Session and Parameter handling is a requirement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/).

Comment: I was not sure if thid library would meet my requirements anf if its still actively developed

Comment: Yup. It's still in development, but not as active as Qt :) It's very lightweight & clean.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using the Pion library for about 8 months.  It is simply fantastic !

http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library/source-code-documentation

4.26.13 - There is an Updated Library Site: [Pion Online Library](https://support.cloudmeter.com/forums/21056797-Pion-Online-Library)

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results combining Qt's [QtNetwork](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html) and [QtWebkit](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html) components. With this combination you will get cookie, session and paramter handling. Given that you are writing a frontend, the rest of Qt might be useful as well.

Comment: I'm already using Qt but as I have to develop a library that should not only used in that application depending on Qt would be a drawback. However, I dig into that - thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Mythli I can appreciate where you're coming from, I try to avoid on Qt as much as possible in my reusable code. Unfortunately though, sometimes, it makes things too easy :).